# How do I track an anonymous email sender?

Tags: anonymity, gmail

I'm getting dirty and filthy mails send from past 2 years in my GMail account. I tried to ignore it, but it is getting filthier day by day. I need some advice and help.

Comment: Add to spam filter and report to google?

Comment: are you receiving the messages from the same email address ?

Comment: Your question is too broad if you may give us more information.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by @BadSkillz, use a spam filter. however if you really want to know more about the person who sent the email, you can look for the IP address of the sender in the Email header.

more information [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Trace-an-Email)